# Bootstrap button loading state while waiting SignalR function result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, signalr

I'm learning MVC, Bootstrap, jQuery and SignalR. I've managed to get up a simple view and a simple SignalR function. This is working but I wanted to add a some sort of wait indicator if the SignalR task is taking a long time to execute. I tried to stateful button from getboostrap.com but for some reason cannot get it to work.

Here is my client code:

```
    <h2>Employees</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEmployees" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off">
    Get Employees
</button>
<div id="result">

</div>
@section scripts
     <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {      
        var service = $.connection.serviceHub;
        service.client.GetEmployees = function (html) {
            $("#result").html(html);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnEmployees').on('click', function () {
                var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
                service.server.printAllEmployees();
                $btn.button('reset');
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
End Section
```

I'm trying to set the button to loading state, execute SignalR function and return the button to normal state. The SignalR function sleeps for 5 seconds and returns me a list. The button stays the same for the duration. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always ask too soon and end up answering my own questions :) Well anyways, I had the basics messed up with jQuery and returned my button to the normal state in wrong place. Of course I have to wait for the answer from the SignalR before resetting the button. Here is the corrected jQuery part:

```
$(function () {      
        var service = $.connection.serviceHub;
        service.client.GetEmployees = function (html) {
            $("#result").html(html);
            $('#btnEmployees').button('reset');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnEmployees').on('click', function () {
                var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
                service.server.printAllEmployees();
            });
        });
    });
```